# Terraform for AKS Application Gateway Ingress Controller 502 and its subnet peering issue

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, ingress-controller

its works fine when:

1. everything build on azure portal
2. enable agic in kubernetes service networking
3. import self signed ssl cert
4. host table mapping

When deploy by terrform:

1. deploy a web page, using application gateway ingress controller
2. deploy aks, vnet, subnet by terraform
3. enable agic by ingress_application_gateway blocks

so now, got a auto-generated vnet, application gateway and public ip in the auto-generated resource group, and a resource group A contains the aks and the application gateway subnet vnet

I am thinking about peering the aks vnet and the vnet that contains application gateway subnet, however they are in the same address space. Any idea or good way to fix

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {
  name                = "${var.aks_name}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  dns_prefix          = "aksxxx"

  kubernetes_version        = var.aks_version
  automatic_channel_upgrade = "stable"
  private_cluster_enabled   = false
  node_resource_group       = "${var.rg_name}-node-group"
  
  sku_tier = "Free"

  oidc_issuer_enabled       = true
  workload_identity_enabled = true

  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "azure"
    dns_service_ip = "10.20.0.10"
    service_cidr   = "10.20.0.0/16"
  }

  ingress_application_gateway {
    subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.appgwsubnet.id
    #subnet_cidr = "10.225.0.0/16"
    gateway_name = "appgw-ingress"
  }

  default_node_pool {
    name                 = "defaultnp"
    vm_size              = "Standard_B2ms"
    orchestrator_version = var.aks_version
    # vnet_subnet_id       = data.azurerm_subnet.aks_node_subnet.id
    type                 = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    enable_auto_scaling  = true
    node_count           = 1 
    min_count            = 1 
    max_count            = 2

    node_labels = {
      role = "general"
    }
  }

  identity {
    type         = "SystemAssigned"
    #identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.aks_service_pricipal.id]
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [default_node_pool[0].node_count]
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_role_assignment.aks_role_assignment
  ]

  tags = {
    "managed_by" = "terraform"
  }
}

# # # =================== Node pool NSG ===========
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "aks_nodepool_nsg" {
  name                = "nsg-${var.aks_nodepool_name}"
  location            = "${var.azure_region_map["az1"]}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  tags = {
    "managed_by" = "terraform"
  }
}

# # # =================== Node pool Vnet =====================
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "aks_node_vnet" {
  name                = "vnet-${var.aks_nodepool_name}"
  location            = "${var.azure_region_map["az1"]}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  address_space       = ["10.224.0.0/12"]

  subnet {
    name           = "aks-subnet"
    address_prefix = "10.224.0.0/16"
    security_group = azurerm_network_security_group.aks_nodepool_nsg.id
  }

  subnet {
    name = "ingress-appgateway-subnet"
    address_prefix = "10.225.0.0/16"
  }

  tags = {
    "managed_by" = "terraform"
  }
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "appgwsubnet" {
  name                 = "ingress-appgateway-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.aks_node_vnet.name
  #address_prefixes     = ["10.225.0.0/24"]
}
```

auto-generated rg for vent, contains the apic
[image]
same rg for aks and vnet
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to provision the Application Gateway AKS cluster with the terraform configuration and I was able to achieve the requirement successfully.

Azure does not allow VNet peering between virtual networks that have overlapping address spaces. Each VNet in Azure should have a distinct address space. If there is an overlap, you have to reconfigure your network to make sure that the VNets use unique and non-overlapping CIDR blocks.

It looks like you are using Terraform to set up a Kubernetes cluster and a virtual network that includes a default node pool and an Application Gateway. To fix the 502 error, you have to check that your Application Gateway can properly direct traffic to your AKS cluster.

**My demo terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vk"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "demovk-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example_aks" {
  name                 = "demovk-aks-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.1.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example_appgw" {
  name                 = "demovk-appgw-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.2.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example_aks" {
  name                = "demovk-aks-cluster"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  dns_prefix          = "exampleaks"

  default_node_pool {
    name             = "default"
    node_count       = 1
    vm_size          = "Standard_DS2_v2"
    vnet_subnet_id   = azurerm_subnet.example_aks.id
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "azure"
    service_cidr   = "10.3.0.0/16"
    dns_service_ip = "10.3.0.10"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example_appgw_ip" {
  name                = "demovk-appgw-ip"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "example_appgw" {
  name                = "demovk-appgw"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku {
    name     = "Standard_v2"
    tier     = "Standard_v2"
    capacity = 2
  }

  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "gateway-ip-configuration"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.example_appgw.id
  }

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "frontend-ip-configuration"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.example_appgw_ip.id
  }

  frontend_port {
    name = "http-port"
    port = 80
  }

  backend_address_pool {
    name = "backend-address-pool"
  }

  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = "http-settings"
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    path                  = "/"
    port                  = 80
    protocol              = "Http"
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = "http-listener"
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = "frontend-ip-configuration"
    frontend_port_name             = "http-port"
    protocol                       = "Http"
  }

  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = "http-routing-rule"
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = "http-listener"
    backend_address_pool_name  = "backend-address-pool"
    backend_http_settings_name = "http-settings"
    priority                   = 100  # Define a priority for the rule
  }
}
```

I have given this for demo purposes with the AKS cluster and not included Ingress controller as Issuse was mentioned as network peering IP Addresses.

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]